# Change event for textarea in ember

Tags: ember.js, textarea

So i have this textarea

```
{{textarea value=model.description key-press="upload" required=true rows="5" aria-describedby=describedby}}
```

as you can see above the keypress event works just fine i.e it is able to trigger the upload action

Now when i replace key-press with change or onchange the upload action dose not get fired. Here is the code

```
{{textarea value=model.description onchange="upload" required=true rows="5" aria-describedby=describedby}}
```

How to call change event action in ember for textarea??

Answer (score 2):

`TextArea` is extending `TextSupport` so here are the events [supported by inbuilt](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextSupport.html),

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                    |                |
| event              | attribute name |
+--------------------+----------------+
| new line inserted  | insert-newline |
|                    |                |
| enter key pressed  | insert-newline |
|                    |                |
| cancel key pressed | escape-press   |
|                    |                |
| focusin            | focus-in       |
|                    |                |
| focusout           | focus-out      |
|                    |                |
| keypress           | key-press      |
|                    |                |
| keyup              | key-up         |
|                    |                |
| keydown            | key-down       |
+--------------------+----------------+
```

If you want to trigger action for onchange then you can try below options,

1. Instead of `{{textarea` you can use normal `<text-area` like the below

   `<textarea value={{appName}} onchange={{action 'onTextFiledChange'}} />`
2. `onchange` event also triggering upon the `focus-out` for text-area,

   `{{textarea value=appName focus-out='onTextFiledChange' }}`
3. You can create your own component by extending the `TextArea`

   `{{my-textarea value=appName onTextFiledChange='onTextFiledChange'}}`

Have a look [at this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/cc752850c399404719876f4dda797b41?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-textarea.hbs)

Comment: the first option is not workinh
can use the second option as i am not directly inserting values in textarea

Comment: For the first option, if you are using it in component then you need to have  `onTextFiledChange`  actions defined in component, if its in template say `dashboard.hbs` then you should have actions `onTextFiledChange` in `dashboard.js` controller

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this ember has some problems with events on input helpers.

```
 <textarea value={{model.description}} onchange={{action "upload" value="target.value"}} >
```

Comment: this is what i tried
    <textarea value={{model.description}} onchange={{action 'upload'}} ></textarea>
for some reason the upload action is not called

Comment: I recommend you use `oninput` instead of `onchange`. `onchange` is only fired on focus out, while `oninput` is fired _just before_ `keyup` iirc.